# Using switch to display specific drop down menu options

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement

New to Javascript and am trying to create a simple switch statement to display and hide specific selection options from drop down menus. Not sure what I am doing wrong. All help is appreciated. Thanks

```js
function showHall() {
    var x = document.getElementById("schoolName").value;

    switch (x) {
        case "williams_college":
            document.getElementById("williamsHall").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("albanyHall").style.display = "none";
            break;
        case "suny_albany":
            document.getElementById("albanyHall").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("williamsHall").style.display = "none";
            break;

        default:
            document.getElementById("albanyHall").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("williamsHall").style.display = "none";
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <th>Select School:</th>
    <td>
        <select id="schoolName" colspan="2" onchange="showHall()">
            <option value="select_school" selected="selected">Select Your School</option>
            <option value="suny_albany">SUNY ALBANY</option>
            <option value="williams_college">WILLIAMS COLLEGE</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Hall:</th>
    <td>
        <select id="williamsHall" colspan="2">
            <option selected value="select_school">Select Your Hall</option>
            <option value="AGARD">AGARD</option>
            <option value="ARMSTRONG">ARMSTRONG</option>
            <option class="optionHall" value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
            <option class="optionHall" value="HALL NOT ASSIGNED">HALL NOT ASSIGNED</option>
        <select id="albanyHall" colspan="2">
            <option selected value="select_school">Select Your Hall</option>
            <option value="HALL1">ALBANY HALL1</option>
            <option value="HALL2">ALBANY HALL2</option>
            <option value="HALL3">ALBANY HALL3</option>
            <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
            <option value="HALL NOT ASSIGNED">HALL NOT ASSIGNED</option>
            </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Code is fine, you are missing a closing `</select>` of williamsHall

Comment: The missing tag was just an oversight. Corrected it still does not correct the issue.

Comment: Patrick, the problem is that the specific drop down menu isn't showing based on my condition selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("schoolName").value;
```

to this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("schoolName");
var val = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
```

**Explanation:**

There is nothing special but just a lack of knowledge about JS. `.value` property is not used to get the selected value of a drop down instead it gives us an array(`.options`) and a `.selectedIndex` which combinedly gives us the chance to use the `.value` indirectly on the selected `<option>`.

Comment: This did not work either. the jfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Patti/u77rmaae/11/

Comment: This didn't work in the jfiddle, but with Seano666's help it is working in my site now. Thanks Mohammad!

Comment: Also, Mohammad. Since I am not sure why my previous code didn't work, can you explain a bit about how this works? I would really like to understand it a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Something is weird with the way JSFiddle is handling your JavaScript in that fiddle.  I moved your JavaScript into script tags above the HTML and it seems to work.  I also set the select elements to display as inline instead of block (they are inline elements).  Seems to work ok, I think Mohammad was on the right track.  Check this out.

http://jsfiddle.net/seano666/2jufk40L/

```
document.getElementById("williamsHall").style.display = "inline";
```

Comment: Thanks Seano666. That was the problem with the jfiddle, and it is working in my site with the inline display. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It indeed works with `block` as well but this is nice.